# jQuery get() method with callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I'm researching on jQuery as a apprentice to jQuery.

In my **jindex2.html** file, I have used below jQuery code block to get data from a external file called **test.asp**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("btn1").click(function(){
    $.get("test.asp", function(content, status){
      alert("This is the content of the file :- " + content + "\nStatus is :- " + status);
    });
  });
});
```

Content of the **test.asp** file is as below.

```
<%
response.write("Mohan Perera from Panadura")
%>
```

Below I have display my whole code of **jindex2.html** file.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").click(function(){
    $("#img1").hide();
  });
});
  
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("btn1").click(function(){
    $.get("test.asp", function(content, status){
      alert("This is the content of the file :- " + content + "\nStatus is :- " + status);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#panel, #flip {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #5d90fd;
}

#panel {
  padding: 50px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Image Disappear</h2>
<p>This jquery application will help us to make invisible the below image</p>
<img src="imgeJquery.png" id="img1" /><br/>

<div id="flip">Click on this !</div>
<div id="panel">Because time is valuable, we deliver quick and easy learning.<br>
    At W3Schools, you can study everything you need to learn, in an accessible and handy format.</div><br/>

<form>
  <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Click !"/>
</form>
```

The other two jQuery I have used are working properly. But the above mentioned one is not working. I wanted to display the content of the **test.asp** file in an alert box, once I click on the *btn1* (Click !). Please help me to do that, by showing my error here.

Comment: Prefix `#` for ID selector i.e. `$("#btn1")`, May be a typo while posting OP

Comment: On small **improvement** in your code. apart from the question, you asked. no need to use **$(document).ready()** multiple times.Use it once.

Answer (score 3):

In below jQuery use have missed to `#` while adding event to button(id:btn1).

if you are writing based on id `#(tag id) -> #btn1`, if it class `.(tag class) ->.btn1`

Try below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
    $.get("test.asp", function(content, status){
      alert("This is the content of the file :- " + content + "\nStatus is :- " + status);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I changed as you suggest. But no any respond even click on the button.  **Note :** test.asp file also in the same directory.

Comment: there is no any error or anything in the browser console. (I'm using Chrome)

Answer (score 1):

Select your button element by its Id with # at the beginning

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
    $.get("test.asp", function(content, status){
      alert("This is the content of the file :- " + content + "\nStatus is :- " + status);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I changed as you suggest. But no any respond even click on the button. **Note :** test.asp file also in the same directory.

Comment: you have a duplicated answer and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.get("demo_test.asp", function(data, status){
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
    });
});
```

And Your Button Should be like this

```
<button>get the result back</button>
```

Comment: No.. This method also not working.. No any respond even click the button. **Note :** test.asp file also in the same directory.